# How to list all groups members of a ldap group?

Tags: ldap, plone, python-ldap

I have Plone 3 with LDAP, I have a lot of groups and users in it. I would like to get all groups members for a specific group.

```py
groupe_id = "mygroup"
gtool = getToolByName(self, 'portal_groups')
group = gtool.getGroupById(groupe_id)
members = group.getAllGroupMembers()
```

Here members always returns `[]` but actually, I do have some users in my group.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer might be: you can't.

When you (or Plone) asks ldap for a list of users ldap may decide that it finds too many results and instead simply returns basically an empty list.  For this reason it is usually good to change the settings in the Users and Groups control panel and switch on 'many users' and maybe also 'many groups'.  For example, this makes sure the 'Show all users' button is not shown.

In [collective.setdefaulteditor](https://github.com/zestsoftware/collective.setdefaulteditor/blob/master/collective/setdefaulteditor/utils.py#L41) I work around this by using portal_membership.searchForMembers(login=char) and then for char iterating over a, b, etcetera

(That does not search for members in a particular group, by the way.)

It is really ugly, so I am hoping for a better answer so I can update this tool. :-)

Comment: That's strange. When I use LDAPBrowser I am able to browse all members of any group...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about plone, but it is based on a posix structure you can easly do this.

```
import ldap

con = ldap.initialize('ldap://127.0.0.1')
con.simple_bind_s('cn=myuser', 'oh_yeah')
groups = con.search_s('dc=rkf,dc=org',
                      ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                      'objectclass=posixgroup',
                      ['memberuid'])

for a in groups:
    print 'Group:', a[0]
    print 'Members:', a[-1].get('memberuid')
```